# What does the "pull" parameter do in drone?

Tags: continuous-integration, drone.io

In working with drone I've seen several cases where `pull: true` is set in a step. Though it's not clear if that's needed since some steps omit it.

It is used [in](http://plugins.drone.io/drone-plugins/drone-s3-cache/) [several](http://plugins.drone.io/meltwater/drone-cache/) [examples](http://plugins.drone.io/devops-israel/drone-lambda/) on the drone website but not explained.

PS: I'm writing this and answering my own question because I had trouble finding to docs to explain this and wanted to make it easier for others to find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You see `pull: true` a lot because the drone 0.X default was to not upgrade images. Since drone 1.0 the default is to upgrade images.

### Drone 1.0 [docs](https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/docker/syntax/images/) say:

> If the image does not exist in the local cache, Drone instructs Docker to pull the image automatically. You will never need to manually pull images.
>
> If the image is tagged with :latest either explicitly or implicitly, Drone attempts to pull the newest version of the image from the remote registry, even if the image exists in the local cache.

```
pull: if-not-exists # only pull the image if not found in the local cache
pull: always # always pull the newest version of the image
pull: never # never pull the image and always use the image in the local cache
```

### Drone 0.8.0 [docs](https://0-8-0.docs.drone.io/images/) say:

> Drone does not automatically upgrade docker images. Example configuration to always pull the latest image when updates are available:

```
pipeline:
  build:
    image: golang:latest
    pull: true
```

This is because reproducibility of the CI is key, and further updates could break your build. [source](https://scalacenter.github.io/platform/ci-integration.html)